# Stop form submitting if one of a checkbox group is not selected

Tags: jquery

I try to stop the submit on a form, if minimum of one of few checkbox is not selected.
But I don't find solution.

HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="idgroup" name="group[1]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="idgroup" name="group[2]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="idgroup" name="group[3]" value="1" />
```

JQUERY :

```
$("#form2").submit(function(e) {
  $('input[id=idgroupe]').each(function () {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      return true;
    }
  });
  alert("Please select a minimum of one group.");
  return false;
});
```

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Using duplicate ids is invalid; instead, you can select the checkboxes by name using [`[name^="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector and check how many items are checked using the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector:

```
$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    if ($("input[name^='group']:checked", this).length === 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default set Submit to disabled by this

`$('#ButtonId').attr('disabled','disabled');`

and on Check Box Selection check values & set to enabled.

or on Submit Check Checkbox values if not give a error or go ahead.

Comment: _"or on Submit Check Checkbox values if not give a error or go ahead."_ - That's what the OP has already tried to do, but their code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#form_check').on('submit', function (e) {
  if ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length === 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('Please select a minimum of one group.');
      return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ID Must be unique.

Use class instead

```
<input type="checkbox" class="idgroup" name="group[1]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="idgroup" name="group[2]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="idgroup" name="group[3]" value="1" />
```

**js**

```
$("#form2").submit(function (e) {
    if ($("input.idgroup:checked").length === 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Please select a minimum of one group.");
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/yKU68/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zQ6v2/) should work fine for you

```
$("#form2").submit(function(e) {
    if($("input[gid='idgroup']:checked").length == 0){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Please select a minimum of one group.");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    <script  src="jquery.js"> </script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#form2").submit(function(e) {

        var flag=0;
        $('input[id="idgroup"]').each(function () {
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                flag=1;
                }
        });
        if(!flag){
            alert("Please select a minimum of one group.");
            return false
        } 
        else
         return true;
    });
    });



</script>

<form action="new.htm" method="post" id="form2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="idgroup" name="group[1]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="idgroup" name="group[2]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="idgroup" name="group[3]" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#form2").submit(function (e) {
 if (jQuery('.idgroup input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
         return true;

  }else{
         alert("Error");
         return false;
  }
 });
```